# how to use ssh to forward the telnet trafic

Tags: networking, ssh, proxy, ssh-tunnel

I have to run a `telnet` connection between two network elements. The server is located after a firewall, and the IP address of the client can not connect it.
My idea is to use a third server as a proxy. To do this I thought of using the command `ssh server ip -D8888 bridge` and configure any proxy on the client: `ALL_PROXY socks5:ipserverbridge`.

And finally run the command `telnet ServerIP`. But unfortunately it doesn't run.

Comment: well, you don't need a SOCKs proxy as it has been described. simply create an SSH tunnel between a local port and the destination server port, and then point the telnet client to `127.0.0.1 <local tunnel port>`. all traffice entering the tunnel on the local side will come out servers tunnel port, so its like a direct connection.

Comment: "doesn't run" is not a thing to diagnose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the network hierarchy is `client -> proxy -> server` and each adjacent pair sees each other, then you can do this using local port forwarding:

```
ssh -­NTfL 2323:server:23 proxy
```

and then you can connect to telnet server over this channel:

```
telnet localhost 2323
```

If your configuration differs, you should adjust these steps.